# Rational points on curves x^p + y^p = 1 in the open unit square, for p > 0

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, foliations

For each real p > 0, let C<sub>p</sub> = {(x,y) ∊ (0, 1)<sup>2</sup>  |  x<sup>p</sup> + y<sup>p</sup>  =  1}.

It is easy to see that each C<sub>p</sub> is topologically an open interval that is the interior of a smoothly embedded closed interval with endpoints at (1,0) and (0,1).

In fact, the C<sub>p</sub> are the leaves of a real analytic foliation of the open unit square (0, 1)<sup>2</sup>.

Let X = {p ∊ ℝ+  |  C<sub>p</sub> ∩ ℚ<sup>2</sup> ≠ ∅}.

Let Y = {p ∊ X  |  C<sub>p</sub> ∩ ℚ<sup>2</sup> is infinite}.

Let Z = {p ∊ Y  |  C<sub>p</sub> ∩ ℚ<sup>2</sup> is dense in C<sub>p</sub>}.

**Question**: What is known about the topology of the subsets Z ⊂ Y ⊂ X of ℝ+ ?

Of course, the cardinality of X is aleph<sub>0</sub>.

Clearly {1,2} ⊂ Z, and thanks to Wiles's proof of FLT, no integer p ≥ 3 belongs to X.

Comment: Three comments: (a) Faltings' theorem should imply that no rational $p$ other than 1,2 can belong to $Y$.  (b)  Bombieri-Pila type results (see https://ems.press/content/serial-article-files/7859 ) should imply that for irrational $p$, the number of rational points on $C_p$ of height at most $N$ is $O(N^{\varepsilon})$ for any fixed $\varepsilon$.  (c) one might possibly be able to say more assuming some standard conjectures in transcendence theory such as Schanuel's conjecture, but I am not an expert in these matters.

Comment: For $p$ rational, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem#Rational_exponents) and references within. @TerryTao You have infinitely many rational points for $p=1/m$ or $2/m$, but not for any others.